# Nginx Rewrite Rule for Special Charachter

Tags: nginx, special-characters

I have one URL as `www.xyz.com/api/abcdefgh^ijklmn`.

I want to redirect this URL `www.xyz.com/api/abcdefgh%5ijklmn`.

Can some one suggest what will be Nginx Redirect rule for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a Redirect Rule and it working perfectly fine.

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(/.*)[\^](.*)$) {
  return 301 $1%5E$2;
}
```

Just make sure you are writing this in **location** directive.